# Using adjustResize pushes up my tabbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabbar

I am currently working on an Android project, and I have a problem with the windowSoftInputMode attribute in my AndroidManifest.xml.

I have this type of layout :

```
<FrameLayout>
    <DrawerLayout>
        <!-- This is where the main content of my application is -->
        <Fragment>
        </Fragment>
    </DrawerLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <!-- This is my handmade TabBar -->
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I first used this in my activity :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

But when I focus an EditText, all my layout is pushed up, behind the Android status bar. This is the expected behaviour of adjustPan, but this is not how I want my app to react.

I would like that, when my keyboard appears, it handles the resizing of what is inside my Fragment, so I put this in my manifest :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

The problem is that my handmade TabBar is pushed up by the keyboard, with the content of my fragment, and I don't want this behavious, I just want to resize the content of my fragment, without my TabBar being pushed up.

I tried to modify my layout, but I really don't know how to do that.

Thank you for the help you could give me.